# Proving Tychonoff's theorem with the Compactness theorem of logic

Tags: general-topology, logic, compactness, model-theory, first-order-logic

It seems to be known that Tychonoff's Theorem for Hausdorff spaces and the Compactness theorem of first order logic are both equivalent over ZF to the ultrafilter lemma. Does anyone know a slick proof for the implication "Compactness Theorem $\rightarrow$ Tychonoff for Hausdorff spaces" (without using the ultrafilter lemma as an intermediate step)?

Comment: What's wrong with using the ultrafilter lemma as an interpolant?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: In order to fully appreciate the usefulness of some (simple) argument, it is nice to know a different (and possibly more complicated) approach. Also, if you have a different approach, you can compare with the former approach to better understand the role played, for example, by the ultrafilter lemma.

Comment: I think a proof of the form "To $\prod X_i$, associate the first order theory $T$, ... , $T$ is obvioiusly finitely satisfiable, satisfiability of T implies that $\prod X_i$ is compact" would be more aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: @Dominik: If anything, then proving that $2^X$ for some set $X$ (probably the disjoint union of the spaces), and then finding a theory describing the space itself being closed, or something.

Comment: @Andre: I think that in cases of weak choice principles it's usually quite easy to see where they are needed. We use ultrafilters to generate some sort of canonical families, and we use the Hausdorff property for a canonical choice from those families.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose that we have a family of compact Hausdorff space $(X_i, \tau_i)$ where $\tau_i$ is the topology and $i$ ranges over an index set $I$. Assume that the product $X = \prod_i X_i$ is not compact, so there is an open cover $(W_\alpha: \alpha < \kappa)$ of $X$ which does not have a finite subcover. We define a language and a consistent theory and then apply the compactness theorem to get a point in $X - \bigcup_\alpha W_\alpha$.

W.l.o.g, assume that each $W_\alpha = \prod_i W_{\alpha,i}$ for $W_{\alpha,i} \in \tau_i$ and $spt(W_\alpha) = \{i: W_{\alpha,i} \neq X_i\}$ is finite.

The language consists of

- constants $c_i$ for $i \in I$;
- for each $i$ and each $U \in \tau_i$, a unary predicate $P_{i,U}$.

The intended meaning of $(c_i: i \in I)$ is a (non-standard) point in $X - \bigcup_\alpha W_\alpha$; and $P_{i,U}(x)$ means $x \in U$.

The theory $T$ consists of

- $P_{i,X_i}(c_i)$;
- for each $\alpha$, $\bigvee_{i \in spt(W_\alpha)} \neg P_{i,W_{\alpha,i}}(c_i)$ (i.e., $(c_i: i \in I) \not\in W_\alpha$);
- for each finite $F \subset \tau_i$, if $\bigcup_{U \in F} U = X_i$ then the sentence $(\forall x) (P_{i,X_i}(x) \to \bigvee_{U \in F} P_{i,U}(x))$ is in $T$;
- if $C = X_i - U$ is closed and $U_0, U_1 \in \tau_i$ are s.t. $U_i \cap C \neq \emptyset$ and $U_0 \cap U_1 \cap C = \emptyset$, then the sentence $\neg P_{i,U_0}(c_i) \vee \neg P_{i,U_1}(c_i)$ is in $T$.

By the assumption that $W_\alpha$'s do not have a finite subcover, $T$ is consistent. So take a model $M$ of $T$, let $\mathcal{C}_i$ be the set of $X_i - U$ s.t. $U \in \tau_i$ and $M \models \neg P_{i,U}(c_i)$. Then $\mathcal{C}_i$ has finite intersection property and by compactness $\bigcap \mathcal{C}_i$ is non-empty. By the last set of sentences in $T$, $\bigcap \mathcal{C}_i$ is a singleton $\{p_i\}$ (here we need Hausdorff-ness). The point $(p_i: i \in I)$ is not covered by any $W_\alpha$.

Comment: How do you deal with the part where you assume $W_\alpha$ to be a basic open set without the axiom of choice ?

Comment: @Max By definition, an open set in the product space is a union of basic open sets. But I admit that $(W_\alpha: \alpha < \kappa)$ is somehow misleading and should be replaced by $(W_j: j \in J)$ where $J$ is an index set.

Comment: I know that, but it seems to me you have to somehow choose the basic open sets that consistute your union. What I'm saying is I don't see how, without the axiom of choice, for any family $(W_i)_{i\in I}$ there would be a family $(V_j)_{j\in J}$ such that they have the same union. When $I$ is finite, induction proves it, but when it isn't, I don't see how you can prove this without the axiom of choice. You can't just say "for $i\in I$, let $(V_j)_{j\in J_i}$ such that...", because you have to choose those $V_j$'s (there may be many such families)

Comment: @Max Let $(W_j: j \in J)$ be given. For each $j$, let $\mathcal{W}_j = \{V: V \text{ is a basic open subset of } W_j\}$. By definition, $W_j = \bigcup \mathcal{W}_j$.

Comment: Oh right I'm stupid I always forget this trick ! It's not that $W_j$ is a union of basic open sets, it's that $W_j$ is *the* union of all the basic open sets it contains.

Comment: Hi. Do you have a reference where I could read more about this proof? Thank you!

Comment: @RicardoCorralesBarquero I worked out this when I prepared lectures on compactness for students. So I don't know whether there is any other reference.

Comment: I stumbled upon this while I was writing my undergrad thesis and when I do not get why are you using this closed set in the last set of axioms. It looks like it works just if you write $\neg P_{i, U}(x) \vee \neg P_{i, V}(x)$ for any $U \cap V = \emptyset$ open sets, morover I do not see how this theory is even satisfiable with this last axiom. I do not see an easy way to choose $c$ such that a finite number of both 2nd and 4th type axioms are satisfied. Nevertheless nice proof and I would cite a version of it in my thesis

Comment: @JanczarKnurek Just to clarify, you mean the following for a substitute of the fourth set of axioms: for each $i$, if $U,V\in\tau_{i}$ with $U\cap V=\emptyset$ the sentence $\forall x\, (\neg P_{i,U}(x)\vee\neg P_{i,V}(x))$. Is this correct? Also, to answer your question, I think the way you choose the constants is by taking those whose subindices occur in the $W_{\alpha,i}$ which make up the finitely many $W_{\alpha}$ mentioned in a finite subset of the theory. That is, the domain of the model will be precisely the (finite) set of those subindices. Am I not correct?

Comment: @JanczarKnurek Also, did you write a proof of this in your undergraduate thesis? Is it accesible? I would like to learn it, as I am trying to work out the details and I find this application of compactness clever and difficult.