# Tychonoff's Theorem via the Compactness Theorem for propositional logic

Tags: general-topology, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to prove Thychonoff's Theorem using the Compactness Theorem for propositional logic.

A space $X$ is compact if and only if every collection $C$ of closed subsets of $X$ having the finite intersection property has nonempty intersection.

Hence, I am trying to show that given a family of compact spaces $\{X_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ then their product $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_{i}$ is compact by showing that an arbitrary family $C$ of closed subsets of $X$ having the f.i.p. has non-empty intersection.

I run into trouble defining the appropriate set $S$ of propositional formulas. And, in fact it seems we may need the $X_{i}$ to be also Hausdorff, since once $S$ is shown to be satisfiable it seems reasonable to use any assignment satisfying $S$ in order to define a non-empty set (perhaps a single point) which will be contained in $\cap C$ and thus show that the intersection is non-empty.

May someone point me in the right direction? Or perhaps there is a more direct argument not relying on the f.i.p. formulation of compactness?

Disclaimer: I have not learned first order logic yet. Hence, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427667/proving-tychonoffs-theorem-with-the-compactness-theorem-of-logic) related question does not really answer mine, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of compact spaces, and let $X = \prod_{i\in I} X_i$. Let $C$ be a family of closed subsets of $X$ with the f.i.p.

*Notation:* For $Y_i\subseteq X_i$, let's write $\tilde{Y_i}$ for the set $Y_i\times \prod_{j\neq i} X_i\subseteq X$. The sets $\tilde{U_i}$ with $U_i$ open in $X_i$ form a subbasis for the topology on $X$, so a basic open set has the form $\tilde{U}_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap \tilde{U}_{i_n}$, where each $U_{i_j}$ is open in $X_{i_j}$. Then a basic closed set has the form $\tilde{V}_{i_1}\cup \dots \cup \tilde{V}_{i_n}$, where each $V_{i_j}$ is closed in $X_{i_j}$.

Let's begin with the standard observation that we can replace $C$ with a family of basic closed sets. Indeed, every closed set is the intersection of all the basic closed sets containing it, so letting $$C' = \{V'\mid V'\text{ basic closed, and }V\subseteq V'\text{ for some }V\in C\}$$
we have $\bigcap_{V\in C} V = \bigcap_{V'\in C'} V'$ and $C'$ also has the f.i.p. So we can assume every closed set in $C$ is a basic closed set.

For every closed set $F\subseteq X_i$, introduce a proposition symbol $P_F^i$. A point of $X$ can be written as $(x_i)_{i\in I}$, and we think of $P_F^i$ as meaning "$x_i\in F$".

Now consider the following propositional theory $T$:

1. For all $V\in C$, with $V = \tilde{V}_{i_1}\cup \dots \cup \tilde{V}_{i_n}$, $T$ contains the axiom $$P^{i_1}_{V_{i_1}}\lor \dots \lor P^{i_n}_{V_{i_n}}.$$
2. For all $i\in I$ and all closed sets $F_1,\dots,F_n$ in $X_i$, if $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n}F_j = \varnothing$, then $T$ contains the axiom $$\lnot \bigwedge_{j=1}^{n} P^i_{F_j}.$$
3. For all $i\in I$ and all closed sets $F,F'$ in $X_i$, if $F\cup F'= X_i$, then $T$ contains the axiom $$P^i_{F}\lor P^i_{F'}.$$

I claim that $T$ is satisfiable. By compactness, it suffices to show that we can find an assignment satisfying *all* axioms from schemas 2 and 3, together with finitely many axioms from schema 1, corresponding to finitely many $V_1,\dots,V_m\in C$. By the hypothesis that $C$ has f.i.p., we can pick some $x = (x_i)_{i\in I}\in V_1\cap\dots\cap V_m$. For each proposition symbol $P^i_F$, set $P^i_F$ to be true if $x_i\in F$ and false otherwise. It is straightforward to check that this assignment works.

Since $T$ is satisfiable, there is some assignment $t$ from our proposition symbols to $\{\top,\bot\}$ satisfying $T$.

Fix $i\in I$. I claim that $C_i = \{F\subseteq X_i\mid F\text{ closed, and }t(P^i_F) = \top\}$ has non-empty intersection. Since $X_i$ is compact, it suffices to show that $C_i$ has the f.i.p. Let $F_1,\dots,F_n\in C_i$. If $\bigcap_{j=1}^n F_j = \varnothing$, then the axiom $\lnot\bigwedge_{j=1}^n P^i_{F_j}$ is in $T$, so we cannot have $t(P^i_{F_j}) = \top$ for all $1\leq j\leq n$, contradiction.

Thus we can pick $x_i\in \bigcap_{F\in C_i}F$ for all $i\in I$. I claim that $x = (x_i)_{i\in I}\in\bigcap_{V\in C} V$. For each $V\in C$ with $V = \tilde{V}_{i_1}\cup \dots \cup \tilde{V}_{i_n}$, $T$ contains the axiom $P^{i_1}_{V_{i_1}}\lor \dots \lor P^{i_n}_{V_{i_n}}$. So for some $1\leq j\leq n$, $t(P^{i_j}_{V_{i_j}}) = \top$. Then $V_{i_j}\in C_{i_j}$, so $x_{i_j}\in V_{i_j}$, so $x\in V$.

---

Great! But note that above, we have to use the axiom of choice to pick $x_i\in \bigcap_{F\in C_i}F$ for all $i\in I$. If you want to prove Tychonoff's Theorem from compactness for propositional logic relative to ZF, then you need to additionally assume that each $X_i$ is Hausdorff.

The fix is that when $X_i$ is compact Hausdorff, the set $\bigcap_{F\in C_i}F$ is a singleton $\{x_i\}$, so there is no choice to be made. Suppose $x,y\in \bigcap_{F\in C_i}F$ with $x\neq y$. Since $X_i$ is Hausdorff, we can find disjoint open neighborhoods $U_x$ and $U_y$ of $x$ and $y$, respectively. Let $F_x = X_i\setminus U_x$, and let $F_y = X_i\setminus U_y$. Since $x\notin F_x$, we must have $t(P^i_{F_x}) = \bot$. And since $y\notin F_y$, we must have $t(P^i_{F_y}) = \bot$. But since $U_x\cap U_y = \varnothing$, $F_x\cup F_y = X_i$, so the axiom $P^i_{F_x}\lor P^i_{F_y}$ is in $T$. This is a contradiction.

Note that we only used axiom schema 3 in the choiceless proof for compact Hausdorff spaces. But it didn't hurt to throw these axioms into $T$ in the proof for compact spaces as well.

Comment: Your proof uses notions (such as consistency of a theory) which I have not learned yet. However, from your axiom schema I will try to work out an answer for compact Hausdorff spaces via the Compactness theorem for propositional logic (that is, defining the set S and then proving it is finitely satisfiable, etc). Certainly I will be coming back to your proof as I progress in my learning the concepts. Thanks again!

Comment: @John oh, sorry. You can take "consistent" to be a synonym for "satisfiable" in what I wrote (in fact they are equivalent by the completeness theorem for propositional logic). And a theory is just a set of sentences. What I did was prove that the set $T$ is finitely satisfiable. You don't need to know anything beyond the statement of the compactness theorem to understand what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I returned to this exercise, and I see that my understanding was flawed.  How do the propositional symbols $P_{F}^{i}$ relate to the elements $x\in X$, or the $x_{i}\in X_{i}$ for each $i$? When you say $P_{F}^{i}$ means $x_{i}\in F$, to what $x_{i}$ are you referring to? Do you mean that we have a propositional symbol $P_{F}^{x_{i},i}$ for each $i$, $F\in X_{i}$ closed and $x_{i}\in X_{i}$?

Comment: @John No, I meant what I wrote. The point is this: to show that $C$ has non-empty intersection, we need to produce a point $x$ in the intersection. To produce $x=(x_i)_{i\in I}$, we need to specify $x_i\in X_i$ for each $i$. Somehow this specification should come from a valuation assigned to some propositional variables. Now the key idea is that we can specify a point in a compact Hausdorff space by specifying which closed sets it is an element of. So if the valuation given to us by the compactness theorems says $P_F^i$ is true, then we make sure to pick $x_i$ such that $x_i\in F$.

Comment: @John That is wrong, unfortunately. Remember: we are trying to use the valuation $t$ satisfying $T$ to find a point $x = (x_i)$ in the intersection. You should think of an arbitrary valuation $t\colon \{P^i_F\mid i\in I, F\subseteq X_i\text{ closed}\}\to \{\top,\bot\}$ as an attempt to describe a point $x = (x_i)$ by answering questions about which closed sets its coordinates $x_i$ live in. Of course, not all valuations actually describe points. For example, if $X_0 = [0,3]$ and $t(P^0_{[0,1]}) = t(P^0_{[2,3]}) = \top$, $t$ fails to describe a point, since $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ are disjoint

Comment: Axiom schemas 2 and 3 ensure that every valuation satisfying these axioms actually succeeds in describing a point. Axiom schema 1 ensures that this point is in $\bigcap_{V\in C} V$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write $\cup$ in my previous comment. My reasoning is as follows: if $(x_{i})$ is in the intersection, then for every closed set $V\in C$ with $V=\tilde{V}_{i_1}\cup\ldots\cup\tilde{V}_{i_n}$ we have $x_{i}\in V_{i}$ for some $i$. Therefore, $V_{i}$ is in the collection $\{F\subseteq X_{i}|\text{ $F$ closed and $x_i\in F$}\}$. Hence, it will be in the larger collection $$\bigcup_{x_i\in X_i}\{F\subseteq X_i|\text{ $F$ closed and $x_i\in F$}\}.$$ This is $C_i$, is it not? That is how I came to understand why we want the language and the sentences as you defined them.

Comment: When trying to apply compactness here I asked myself: How do we appropriately describe a point in the intersection? One: that it is in the intersection (axiom schema 1), for which it is necessary to have two: that the the union I defined above have the f.i.p. (hence axiom schema 2) Finally, axiom schema 3 when the Hausdorff property is present. Is my way of thinking appropriate?

Comment: By your description, $C_i$ is just the set of *all* non-empty closed sets in $X_i$ (since every non-empty closed set is a closed set containing $x_i$ for some $x_i\in X_i$).

Comment: Yes, of dear... I just do not see how to connect that $(x_{i})$ is in the intersection (i.e. that it is necessary that the collection $B = \{F\subseteq X_{i}|\text{ $F$ closed and $x_{i}\in F$}\}$ has the f.i.p.) with a proper definition of the symbols and axioms. $B$ is dependent on $x_{i}$ but the $P_{F}^{i}$ and your $C_{i}$ are not, yet $B$ resembles $C_{i}$ since $P_{F}^{i}$ is meant to say $x_{i}\in F$ when true, but not any specific $x_{i}$... I am a bit lost.

Comment: @John I think the most productive thing I can say at this point is that you should reread my answer slowly and carefully. It's precise and correct as written.

Answer (score 0):

I had some lingering issues, and after carefully reading the well-written answer posted by Alex Kruckman I wanted to rework the solution using the open cover definition of compactness in order to display my reasoning in detail, hoping it can be corrected if appropriate. I want to make sure I get this right.

A brief set-up:

> A collection of subsets of a topological space $X$ is *inadequate* if and only if it fails to cover $X$, and *finitely inadequate* if and only if no finite subcollection covers $X$. Then, it is straightforward to check that a topological space $X$ is compact if and only if every finitely inadequate collection of open sets of $X$ is inadequate.
>
> If $\mathcal{C}$ is a finitely inadequate collection of open sets of $X$, then there is a finitely inadequate collection $\mathcal{O}$ of basic open sets of $X$ such that
> $$\bigcup_{V\in\mathcal{C}}V = \bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{O}}U$$
>
> Indeed, simply consider $\mathcal{O} = \{U:\text{$U$ is basic open and $U\subseteq V$ for some $V\in\mathcal{C}$}\}$.

Let $\{(X_{\alpha},\tau_{\alpha}),\alpha\in I\}$ be a collection of compact topological spaces. Based on the set-up above we only need to consider a finitely inadequate collection $\mathcal{O}$ of basic open sets of $X=\prod_{\alpha\in I}X_{\alpha}$. We will use propositional compactness to show that $\mathcal{O}$ is inadequate by describing a point of $X$ which is not covered by $\mathcal{O}$ using a valuation appropriately definied on the right propositional symbols (the language $L$ below) and satisfying the right set of $L$-sentences (the set $S$ below).

How do we define the right $L$ and $S$? Well, let us say $a=(a_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}$ is not covered by $\mathcal{O}$. That is,
$$a\in X-\bigcup_{U\in \mathcal{O}}U$$
This means that for each $U\in \mathcal{O}$ with $U=\bigcap_{\alpha\in J}\tilde{U}_{\alpha}$ for some finite $J\subseteq I$ and $U_{\alpha}\in\tau_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in J$, there is some $\alpha\in J$ such that $a_{\alpha}\not\in U_{\alpha}$.

Therefore, a description of a point of $X$ not covered by $\mathcal{O}$ requires a description of its coordinates in the factor spaces $X_{\alpha}$, which can be accomplished by describing to which open subsets of $X_{\alpha}$ the coordinate does not belong to. Hence, it makes sense that

> for each $\alpha\in I$, our propositional language $L$ has propositional atoms $P_{V}^{\alpha}$, for all $V\in\tau_{\alpha}$. We think of $P_{V}^{\alpha}$ expressing, when true (for a point of $X$), that the $\alpha$-th coordinate (of the point) does not belong to $V$. (e.g. for $a$, that $a_{\alpha}\not\in V$).

Now, let us go back to the particular $a$ not covered by $\mathcal{O}$ I am using to derive what we need. Describing to which open subsets of $X_{\alpha}$ the coordinate $a_{\alpha}$ does not belong to entails a description of the collection
$$A_{\alpha}=\{V\in\tau_{\alpha}:a_{\alpha}\not\in V\}.$$
Indeed, we would like that
$$a_{\alpha}\in X_{\alpha}-\bigcup_{V\in A_{\alpha}}V.$$
Therefore, it is required we describe that $A_{\alpha}$ does not cover $X_{\alpha}$, which since $X_{\alpha}$ is compact, it is the same as saying that $A_{\alpha}$ is finitely inadequate. Indeed, if we want our truth valuation $v:\{\text{$L$-atoms $P_{V}^{\alpha}$}\}\rightarrow\{\top\bot\}$ to truly describes a point not covered by $\mathcal{O}$ by telling us to which open subsets $V$ in the factor space $X_{\alpha}$ the $\alpha$-th coordinate of the point does not live in, we must have $v(P_{V}^{\alpha})=\top$. Hence, it makes sense to consider for each $\alpha\in I$, the collection
$$C_{\alpha} = \{V\in\tau_{\alpha}:v(P_{V}^{\alpha})=\top\},$$
which we would want to be finitely inadequate, just as $A_{\alpha}$ (i.e. $v$ will be defined in such a way that $A_{\alpha}\subseteq C_{\alpha}$)

Let us put this all together by considering the following set $S$ of $L$-sentences:

- (a) For each basic open set $U\in\mathcal{O}$ with $U=\bigcap_{\alpha\in J}\tilde{U}_{\alpha}$ for some finite $J\subseteq I$ and $U_{\alpha}\in\tau_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in J$, we have the $L$-sentence
  $$\bigvee_{\alpha\in J}P_{U_{\alpha}}^{\alpha}$$
  Collectively, these $L$-sentences describe that our truth valuation will express that $\mathcal{O}$ is inadequate by describing a point not covered by $\mathcal{O}$.
- (b) For each $\alpha\in I$ and each finite subset $F\subseteq\tau_{\alpha}$ with $\bigcup_{V\in F}V=X_{\alpha}$, we have the $L$-sentence
  $$\bigvee_{V\in F}\neg P^{\alpha}_{V}$$
  These $L$-sentences express that for each $\alpha\in I$ our truth-valuation-defined collection $C_{\alpha}$ is finitely inadequate.
- (c) For each $\alpha\in I$ and each pair $V,W\in\tau_{\alpha}$ with $U\cap W=\emptyset$, we have the $L$-sentence
  $$P^{\alpha}_{V}\vee P_{W}^{\alpha}$$
  For each $\alpha\in I$, these $L$-sentences express that our truth valuation respects that $X_{\alpha}$ is Hausdorff (these $L$-sentences will be crucial when each factor space $X_{\alpha}$ is also Hausdorff, but will be satisfied regardless)

If $S$ is finitely satisfiable, by propositional compactness it is satisfiable, and let $v$ be a truth valuation satisfying $S$. Then for each $\alpha\in I$ we can define
$$C_{\alpha} = \{V\in\tau_{\alpha} : v(P_{V}^{\alpha}) = \top\},$$
which is wat we wanted.

If for each $\alpha\in I$ the collection $C_{\alpha}$ is finitely inadequate, it is also inadequate, and we can pick (notice the use of the full axiom of choice here!) for each $\alpha\in I$ a point
$$a_{\alpha}\in X_{\alpha}-\bigcup_{V\in C_{\alpha}}V$$
We claim that the point $a=(a_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}$ so chosen is not covered by $\mathcal{O}$. Indeed, suppose it is. Then, there would be $U\in\mathcal{O}$ such that $a\in U$. But $U=\bigcap_{\alpha\in J}\tilde{U}_{\alpha}$ for some finite $J\in I$ and $U_{\alpha}\in\tau_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in J$. Therefore, $a_{\alpha}\in U_{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha\in J$. Now, recall that $v$ satisfies the $L$-sentences in (a), so $v(P^{\alpha}_{U_{\alpha}})=\top$ for some $\alpha\in J$. Therefore, for some $\alpha\in J$ we have $U_{\alpha}\in C_{\alpha}$, i.e. $a_{\alpha}\not\in U_{\alpha}$, which is a contradiction.

Let us then prove that for each $\alpha\in I$, the collection $C_{\alpha}$ is finitely inadequate. Indeed, suppose there is a finite subset $F\subseteq C_{\alpha}$ such that $\bigcup_{V\in F}V = X_{\alpha}$. Clearly, $v(P_{V}^{\alpha}) = \top$ for all $V\in F$. On the other hand, since $v$ satisfies the $L$-sentences in (b) we must have $v(P_{V}^{\alpha}) = \bot$ for some $V\in F$, which is a contradiction.

Finally, we will prove that $S$ is finitely satisfiable. Indeed, let $\Delta\subseteq S$ be a finite subset of $S$. Then there are finitely many basic open sets $U_{1},\ldots, U_{m}\in\mathcal{O}$ occurring in the $L$-sentences of $\Delta$. Since $\mathcal{O}$ is finitely inadequate, we can pick $b=(b_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in I}\in X-(U_{1}\cup\ldots\cup U_{m})$. Define a truth valuation $v_{\Delta}$ by
$$v_{\Delta}(P_{V}^{\alpha}) = \top\text{ if and only if $b_{\alpha}\not\in V$}.$$
It is straightforward to check that $v_{\Delta}$ satisfies all the $L$-sentences in (a)-(c) occurring in $\Delta$.

Regarding the use of the sentences in (c) when we make the additional assumption that each $X_{\alpha}$ is also Hausdorff: Recall that we needed the full axiom of choice to pick for each $\alpha\in I$ a point in
$$Y_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha}-\bigcup_{V\in C_{\alpha}}V$$
This need dissapears when each $X_{\alpha}$ is compact Hausdorff because the previous set is a singleton for each $\alpha\in I$. Indeed, suppose $x\neq y\in Y_{\alpha}$. Since $X_{\alpha}$ is Hausdorff, we can find disjoint $V,W\in\tau_{\alpha}$ with $x\in V$ and $y\in W$. Let $v$ be the truth valuation satisfying $S$. Then,
$$v(P_{V}^{\alpha}\vee P_{W}^{\alpha})=\top,$$
which means $v(\neg P_{V}^{\alpha})=v(\neg P_{W}^{\alpha})=\top$ cannot occur. But since $x\in V$ and $y\in W$, we have $V,W\not\in C_{\alpha}$, which means precisely that $v(\neg P_{V}^{\alpha})=v(\neg P_{W}^{\alpha})=\top$. This is a contradiction, and we must have $x=y$.

Comment: I see no essential difference between your answer and mine.