# Direct proof of Alexander's Subbasis Theorem from Propositional Compactness

Tags: logic, compactness, propositional-calculus

Alexander's Subbasis Theorem (AST) is the following statement:

> A topological space $X$ is compact if and only if there is a subbasis $\mathcal{S}$ for the topology such that every cover of $X$ by elements of $\mathcal{S}$ has a finite subcover.

I can prove the following (over $\mathsf{ZF}$):

- AST $\Rightarrow$ Tychonoff's Theorem for compact Hausdorff spaces $\Rightarrow$ Propositional compactness (PC).
- PC $\Rightarrow$ Boolean Prime Ideal Theorem (eq. Ultrafilter Theorem) $\Rightarrow$ AST.

I know how to show AST $\Rightarrow$ PC more directly, by appropriately topologizing the set $X$ of all valuations of propositional formulas ($X$ will be homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{|L|}$), showing that $X$ is compact iff PC holds, and then applying AST to show that $X$ is a compact space.

However, is there a direct proof of PC $\Rightarrow$ AST? That is, by directly defining an appropriate set of propositional formulas encoding the conclusion of AST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use exactly the same strategy I showed you in my answer to your previous question on [Tychonoff's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4441671/7062). Since it seems you had some lingering questions about that answer, I'll write out the details again for you.

One direction of AST is trivial. Suppose $X$ is compact. Taking $\mathcal{S}$ to be the subbasis consisting of all open sets, every cover of $X$ by elements of $\mathcal{S}$ has a finite subcover.

For the non-trivial direction, suppose $\mathcal{S}$ is a subbasis for the topology on $X$ such that every cover of $X$ by elements of $\mathcal{S}$ has a finite subcover. Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the basis generated by $\mathcal{S}$ (so $\mathcal{B}$ is the set of all finite intersections of sets from $\mathcal{S}$). To show $X$ is compact, it suffices to show that every cover of $X$ by elements of $\mathcal{B}$ has a finite subcover. Equivalently, it suffices to show that if $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of basic open sets from $\mathcal{B}$ such that no finite subfamily covers $X$, then $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ does not cover $X$.

So fix $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ such that no finite subfamily covers $X$. For each $i\in I$, write $U_i = S_i^1\cap\dots\cap S_i^{k_i}$ with each $S_i^j\in \mathcal{S}$. Consider the propositional language consisting of one proposition symbol $P_S$ for each set $S\in \mathcal{S}$, and the propositional theory $T$ consisting of the following two axiom schemes:

1. Whenever $S_1,\dots,S_n\in \mathcal{S}$ and cover $X$, include the axiom $\varphi_{S_1,\dots,S_n}\colon \bigvee_{j=1}^n \lnot P_{S_j}$.
2. For each $i\in I$, include the axiom $\psi_{U_i}\colon \bigvee_{j=1}^{k_i} P_{S_i^j}$.

*Claim 1:* For any point $x\in X$, define a valuation $v_x$ by $$v_x(P_S) = \begin{cases} \top& \text{if }x\notin S\\
\bot&\text{if }x\in S.\end{cases}$$
Then $v_x$ satisfies all axioms from scheme 1, and if $x\notin U_i$, then $v_x$ satisfies axiom $\psi_{U_i}$ from scheme 2.

*Proof of Claim 1:* For scheme 1, suppose $S_1,\dots,S_n\in S$ and cover $X$. Then $x\in S_j$ for some $1\leq j \leq n$, so $v_x(P_{S_j}) = \bot$, and $v_X$ satisfies $\varphi_{S_1,\dots,S_n}$. For scheme 2, suppose $x\notin U_i = S_i^1\cap\dots\cap S_i^{k_i}$. Then there exists $1\leq j\leq k_i$ such that $x\notin S_i^j$, so $v_x(P_{S_i^j}) = \top$, and $v_X$ satisfies $\psi_{U_i}$. $\square$

*Claim 2:* Let $v$ be a valuation which satisfies all axioms from scheme 1. Then there is a point $x\in X$ such that for all $S\in \mathcal{S}$, if $v(P_S) = \top$, then $x\notin S$. Further, if $v$ satisfies axiom $\psi_{U_i}$ from scheme 2, then $x\notin U_i$.

*Proof of Claim 2:* Let $\mathcal{F} = \{S\in \mathcal{S}\mid v(P_S) = \top\}$. Let $S_1,\dots,S_n\in \mathcal{F}$. If $S_1,\dots,S_n$ cover $X$, then $v$ satisfies $\varphi_{S_1,\dots,S_n}$, so there is some $1\leq j\leq n$ such that $v(P_{S_j}) = \bot$. This contradicts the fact that each $S_j\in \mathcal{F}$. So no finite subfamily of $\mathcal{F}$ covers $X$. By our hypothesis on $\mathcal{S}$, $\mathcal{F}$ fails to cover $X$, so there is some $x\in X\setminus \bigcup_{S\in \mathcal{F}} S$. Thus, for all $S\in \mathcal{S}$ such that $v(P_S) = \top$, $x\notin S$. Now suppose $v$ satisfies the axiom $\psi_{U_i}$. Then for some $1\leq j\leq k_i$, $v(P_{S_i^j}) = \top$, so $x\notin S_i^j$, and hence $x\notin U_i$. $\square$

To finish the proof of AST, I claim that the theory $T$ is consistent. A finite subset $\Delta\subseteq T$ includes only finitely many axioms $\psi_{U_{i_1}},\dots,\psi_{U_{i_m}}$ from scheme $2$. By our assumption, $U_{i_1},\dots,U_{i_m}$ does not cover $X$, so there is some point $x$ which is not in any $U_{i_j}$. By Claim 1, the valuation $v_x$ satisfies $\Delta$.

By compactness, $T$ is consistent. Let $v$ be a valuation satisfying $T$. By Claim 2, there is a point $x\in X$ such that $x\notin U_i$ for all $i\in I$. Thus $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ does not cover $X$, as was to be shown.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed answer. Also, last week I carefully read your past answer to the Tychonoff Theorem question, and I thought I had resolved my lingering issues. However, in reading your answer to the Alexander Subbase Theorem I see that the way you think about these types of problems is a bit different than mine, so I decided to post my answer (re-worked via open covers) to the Tychonoff Theorem question. If my "how to" approach to define what's needed is flawed, I would certainly welcome a correction, if you have the time to read it.